# Caml light and finding the prime factors

Tags: programming-challenge, primes, ocaml, factors

I wrote the following Caml light code to find prime factors of a number (part of an early [Project Euler question](http://projecteuler.net/problem=3)).

> **Largest prime factor**
>
> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

```
let rec find_factors target check =
if (check > (int_of_float (sqrt (float_of_int target)))) then [] else
        (find_factors target (check+1))@if target mod check == 0 then 
[ check; (target/check)] else[] ;;

let display n =
print_int n;print_newline();;

do_list display (find_factors 10 1);
print_newline();;
```

I'm very new to functional programming and I suspect I'm all over the place - if anyone would like to give me some tips that would be ideal. :)

Answer (score 5):

I guess that I should not be giving you an answer, but guide you. So, one general remark that I have: stylistically, it would be preferable to see you start with

```
let largest_factor n =
    let rec aux_factor d n =
        ...
    in 
        # some expression involving to aux_factor
```

The idea is that your solution function should be an expression of your problem and nothing else, so `largest_factor number`, not `largest_factor number what_is_that`.

Note that I am talking OCaml here, not sure if the pseudosample I wrote is cromulent Caml Light.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of points regarding efficiency:

- You recompute the square root of `target` at every recursive call of `find_factors`.  You can do better than that.
- You use list concatenation in a \$O(n)\$ algorithm: you can avoid it by prepending the values instead, and post process your result with a list reverse (`List.rev`).

@agravier's answer offers a good hint as to how you may optimize the above points while still supporting a decent interface for your function.

Consider the following functions, which calculate the sum of a list of integers:

```
let rec lsum l =
    match l with
        | [] -> 0
        | x::xs -> x + lsum xs

let rec lsum' acc l =
    match l with
        | [] -> acc
        | x::xs -> lsum (acc+x) xs
```

The first one provides a simple interface which corresponds exactly to the purpose of the function: it's easy to understand and use by just reading its signature. The second one is not as easy to understand (what's that `acc` parameter there?), but it is more efficient: it's a tail recursive definition, which may be optimized to a simple loop. You will want to write function in the second style, but with the interface of the first style.

```
(* simple interface *)
let lsum'' l =
    (* efficient implementation *)
    let rec lsum' acc l = ...
    in lsum' 0 l
```